# Can I use a seperate power supply for a graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I have a prebuilt system that I want to upgrade with a graphics card, but there's not enough extra watts to power a graphics card. Can I glue a second power supply to the top of the case and use the card I have on a shelf, or is this a bad idea?

Comment: You can hook up a second power supply to the 8 pin connectors of the card. It's common practice in rigs where multiple cards are used with a single motherboard. To have the supplies start when you press the power button, you might need a splitter cable for the ATX power connector.

Comment: Best is if you only supply the card with a single PSU, and then you need a riser. Example splitter: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00KCRRT3W/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_il_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=gs4&linkId=b08381b10f0966e4721033c598c1f916&creativeASIN=B07543LNRH&tag=murraynet-21&creative=9325&camp=1789    
Example riser: https://www.amazon.com/Kingwin-Powered-Adapter-Flexible-Extension/dp/B07QBF2X6C/ref=sr_1_15?dchild=1&keywords=pcie+riser&qid=1605766704&sr=8-15

Comment: Additional info: you have two power supply so if you want them both to turn on automatically when you turn on your system, you need to connect the green wire of power supply no1 to green wire of power supply no2, and you need to do the same for black wire.

Comment: Alright, thanks for you help but it looks like this would be a bit more difficult then my skills allow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely possible, but to answer your question, it is a bad idea. The better idea is to just get a single PSU that will support all your devices. Having to "rig" your rig to use dual PSUs would require additional parts that can affect performance, make things untidy, and possibly even damage your hardware.