Very inexplicable, sporadic screen blanking, tried many things, running out of ideas
I am looking for someone's instincts on this one. There are about 16 things it could be, or that I could try, but I am hoping to narrow it down a bit based on someone's experiential knowledge and wisdom.
What's happening:
What's happening, basically, is that my RTX GPU (Zotac, 4090 standard model) is just crashing. The screens (including my VR headset, if I am using it) just go blank suddenly. I can still hear the audio of everything and talk on discord, but then even that goes (last night, I was able to continue talking to my friend on discord for a few hours, it never went all night). The PC basically does a slow crash that it never recovers from.
I've had it even for very low performing games like They Are Billions.
It is getting worse, first it was once or twice per play session, now it's very regular - can't play. Doesn't seem to happen when not playing.
Update: Now it is happening when not playing too. It just happens randomly. Sometimes it works for a whole week, sometimes it won't get past the login screen no matter what I do, and then magically work the next day, or make some small change like moving the RAM to a new slot...
I also sometimes (but not always) see an event in the event viewer: "Display driver nvlddmkm stopped responding and successfully recovered." (it doesn't seem to recover). According to this, it was supposed to be the RAM, which is why I tried replacing the RAM (didn't help).
Note: It's not compatibility. The system was working fine for 2 years, and there were no obvious changes when the problem started last week. The problem just developed suddenly, and is getting worse.
My Guess:
My guess is either the PSU (ruled out) or the GPU itself (tested in another rig, worked fine). One of them has developed some sort of fault, and my best guess (and hope) is the PSU. The PSU has way more than enough power, but it is a less well known brand (and discontinued).
What I've tried (see update below):
I've looked at the temperatures (and enabled logging) and they never spike. I've also updated all possible drivers etc (not MOBO though), and I've tried the GPU at 80% power. I've also ran a full CPU test using intel's tool. I haven't worked in IT for years, but wasn't very good even then :)
Question:
Does anyone have any tips on how I can diagnose whether it is PSU or GPU (or possibly CPU), without testing in another machine? Nobody I know has a PSU big enough to test my GPU on. Also happy for other questions and suggestions, I am looking for your wisdom as I don't trust mine!
Specs:
Talking about a windows 11 box. Other specs are Aerocool Strike-X 1100W Modular Gaming Quiet Fan PSU 80 Plus Gold, Samsung 1TB 970 EVO M.2 NVMe SSD, ASRock Z690 PG Riptide, 32GB RAM, Intel 12900K, NZXT Kraken X63, 280mm CPU Cooler, and there are 2 screens, HDMI and DP.
Update:

Updated everything I can think of including BIOS and drivers, cleaned the case, done as much due diligence as possible
I've replaced the RAM. Still had the issue.
I ran OCCT on the GPU and it crashes within 5 minutes (loud fans, general bluescreen follows if I leave it).
I took the GPU to Scan and let them test it on their bench for 90 mintues, it was fine.
I bought a new PSU when there and put that in. Still have the issue.

So, tomorrow I will disconnect the mobo, take it to scan and also refund the PSU, let them test it, probably try replacing it even if it passes their tests (and be very careful, in case I need to return that too). I'll also get them to test the GPU again, why not.
If it's none of that, it's either the CPU (which is not under warranty!), or something very random like some other faulty part or shorting cable, or it's a combination of things that makes this exponentially more troublesome to diagnose. I am obviously having a lot of stress about this - any recommendations or suggestions most welcome!

First, make sure that all the cables are properly seated. Then, have you tried The Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool? Just to check. And you could try something like FurMark to stress test the GPU.

@AndrewMorton the question is really how to determine if it is the PSU. Bear in mind that it is a 1100W PSU, so I don't have local friends who have a powerful enough PSU to use to test. Are there any ways of determining this? It's an RTX 4090. Passed the CPU tests in your intel tool. Thanks for that suggestion

1100W is more than enough for even the next generation of GPU. I would suspect the cpu or motherboard before the gpu.

@Ramhound def more than enough, but it's a less well known brand, it's old, and I suspect faulty. Seems very much like a power issue. I've tested CPU, and it only only happens with gaming

Is the mainboard BIOS version current? DIMMs on the ASRock QVL list? What are the actual temperatures and voltages you're reading?

@Zac67 thanks, I forgot to update the BIOS. I've had the mobo for years so I doubt it's an issue with DIMMs mismatch. I'll try the BIOS update. CPU and GPU not going over 65

What was last changed? Any hardware change? Crashes since last driver/Windows update?

@Zac67 no changes at all. Just randomly started happening recently. Don't think it coincided with an update but maybe, hard to know exactly when it began. Thanks

@Dr.Kaii RTX 4090 isn't the make and model. From a quick search, I've seen that a replacement graphics card power cable might solve it. For an RTX 4090, there is a possibility that it wants peaks of power in excess of what an older-generation PSU can supply. Can you set your graphics card to limit the peak power?

@AndrewMorton I have tried turning the power down on it by 20% but it didn't make any difference. The make is Zotac, a standard 4090. I don't think I can change the power cable? It's coming straight from the inside of the PSU. FYI I've had it for 2 years, and the PSU for 4 years

Try 50% - a GPU as powerful as that can want sudden big peaks in the power, from what I've read. You might end up needing a PSU designed to work with 12HVPWR, but for how much they cost for nice ones with platinum efficiency, I'm not suggesting that as an answer...

And carefully inspect the power connectors of the graphics card - any hint of acrid electrical burning smell or melted plastic will be a warning.

If it worked yesterday then updating the firmware seems unnecessary. That leads me to an important question. Did it work yesterday or did this problem always exist? I want to remind everyone this system is at least 3 years old. So unless the problem always existed it’s not an incompatibility with the PSU.

@Ramhound indeed, it is not a compatibility issue as it worked "yesterday". It worked for 2 years. This is a very recent, and sudden problem (although it is deteriorating)

you could try a friend's PSU in combination with yours

@AlanBirtles sorry, I thought I mentioned but maybe I forgot - I don't really know anyone in my town with a gaming rig, and the few I do only have 450-550W. I'm surprised there isn't some clever way to find out, something that can be logged that will indicate a sudden power failure or something

yep, you can use their PSU in addition to yours, it'll reduce the load on yours which might fix your problem (if the PSU is the source of your problem) https://superuser.com/questions/1603316/can-i-use-a-seperate-power-supply-for-a-graphics-card https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/m60o6z/can_i_have_a_separate_psu_for_just_the_gpu/

How many power connectors do you have going to the 12VHPWR connector adapter? Ideally it would be as many as possible. If you have the money and are looking for justification to replace the PSU, google for "aerocool strike x 1100w review", then you can browse the Seasonic, Superflower, etc. websites for ATX 3.1 PSUs and then go over reviews. I am not responsible for your spending ;)

@AndrewMorton is it quiet? These high watt PSUs can be loud, but the Aerostrike in my rig is very quiet (but it has "quiet" in the name, this doesn't). There is no adapter, the PSU itself has 3 cables that all go straight into the GPU. There is one second hand for £70, I can afford it, but can't afford a £300 PSU right now

@Dr.Kaii Ah, I had to assume that the GPU had a 12VHPWR connector as there was no link to the model you have. It might be better to ask about the problem on a more chat-like site, such as https://www.reddit.com/r/PCRepair/ than here. Someone else might recognize the symptom of no image but the sound carries on for a little while.

@AndrewMorton see update if you get the chance

@AlanBirtles finally ruled out the PSU, and most likely ruled out the GPU. See edit if poss. Thanks so much for your suggestions thus far, you and everyone else.

@Dr.Kaii As you're lucky enough to live that close to Scan, I suggest that you take the whole computer with you. Maybe they can spot something that doesn't come across via writing. (It could be a solder joint on the M/B that has become unreliable, which is pretty much untraceable without a lot of work.)

@AndrewMorton 2 reasons against that idea: 1) I only got the mobo from them, nothing else, so not sure they would go that far and 2) the issue is so sporadic, I want to try to keep the variables as limited as possible. Given that it can work a whole week, and then not work, makes me already very worried that nothing will happen when I get there tomorrow and back to square one. If that happens, I'll just buy a new motherboard. Either way, I am taking the MOBO and I will ask them to look for things like that, at least so thanks for the idea!

@AndrewMorton when you say replacement cable, do you mean the adapter?

Took the GPU to Scan twice, first time it ran tests (OCCT) without issue for 90 minutes. Second time it immediately crashed with my adapter, so they tried again with their own adapter, and it didn't crash but it threw errors, so they RMA'd it.
Unfortunately, 4090s are end of life now, so they couldn't replace it, and instead offered me a 60% refund.
